# What do you call the circular thing inside a bathtub?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the circular thing inside a bathtub? In the picture above, it's submerged in the water. What do you call that thing, right below the faucet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the tub drain overflow plate, though it's actually above the drain, not the faucet. (The opening in this plate leads to a tube that prevents the tub from overflowing by allowing water to run out even if the drain in the bottom of the tub is stopped.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant below.

Comment: It's below the spout – the faucets are the things one twists to turn the water on and off, though many native speakers also get that wrong.

Comment: *It is coverd by a hair-strainer in the photo, a device intended to allow water to pass through, but prevent hair from getting into and clogging a drain.

Comment: Oh, I see! I've never seen a strainer like that and assumed it was a device to intentionally defeat the overflow mechanism. I'll edit that part out of my answer.